# I don't get the opition "Website using blogdown" in "Project type" after installing the blogdown package

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I'm trying to create a Hugo website using blogdown using RStudio but I don't get the option "Website using blogdown", does someone know how to fix this?

On my Windows computer I have installed and activated the blogdown package, but when I want to create a new project (File -> New project -> ) there is no option type: "Website using blogdown". I have also installed Hugo by using the command `blogdown::install_hugo()`

Comment: What version of R are you using. `install.packages("blogdown", dependencies = T); library("blogdown")`, then close and re-open R Studio then follow the above mentioned path works for me. Appears for me on R3.6.1

Comment: Try to update RStudio: you might be using an old version of RStudio.

Comment: Thanks @MDEWITT but it didn't work for me :( . I am using R version R x64 3.6.1.

Comment: Thans also @YihuiXie, I'm using RStudio Version 1.2.1335, which I hope is the latest version. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck.

Comment: The options available after _File -> New project -> New Directory_ are _New project_, _R Package_, _Shiny Web Application_

Comment: RStudio 1.2.x is enough. Then I guess a certain R package is broken in your system. The conservative way to go is to reinstall all installed R packages.

Comment: Tanks again @YihuiXie I think that starting over from a clean slate would be best, just a follow-up question: what would be the best way to do that? I have uninstalled and reinstalled R and RStudio but somehow all the packages from prior installation where still there? How do I get rid of everything and start from scrach?

Comment: Here is one way to reinstall all installed R packages: `for (lib in .libPaths()) install.packages(.packages(TRUE, lib), lib)`

Comment: @YihuiXie many thanks again! However, it didn't seem to work. Maybe I have missed something? After following your reccomendations this is the options available in the RStudio menue after having loaded the Bookdown package: 1) File -> New project -> New directory, 2) available options:  _Project type: New project, R Package, Shiny Web Application, R package using Rcpp, R package using RcppArmadillo, R package using RcppEigen, R package using devtools_.